# Qt class hierarchy image/pdf

Tags: qt, qt4, class-hierarchy, poster

Do you know of any decent image or pdf of the class hierarchy of Qt 4?

Such as they have for Qt 3:

ftp://ftp.trolltech.com/qt/pdf/3.0/qt30-class-chart.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a class chart for Qt 4.3 here:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/extras/qt43-class-chart.pdf

I'm not aware of any class charts for more recent versions than that.

Comment: Thank you, this should do it